# How to get current row in xlsx file and divide it on the previous one?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I'm using this `class` to write the statistics in `xlsx` files:

```
class DictWriter:
    def __init__(self, workbook, worksheet, fieldnames):
        self.workbook = workbook
        self.worksheet = worksheet
        self.fieldnames = fieldnames
        self.nrow = 1

    def writerow(self, d, condition=0):
        for k in d:
            ncol = self.fieldnames.index(k)
            self.worksheet.write(self.nrow, ncol, d[k])
            self.nrow += 1

    def writeheader(self):
        for ncol, fieldname in enumerate(self.fieldnames):
            self.worksheet.write(0, ncol, fieldname)
```

and using it this way:

```
def file_generator():
    link = "http://linkforexample.com/api/getSomething"
    client = requests.get(link)
    response = client.json()['response']
    if response['httpStatus'] == 200:
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Statistics.xlsx', {'strings_to_numbers': True})
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
        data_table = response['data']['data']
        fieldnames = ["Date", "Advertiser", "Clicks", "Conversions", "Cost", "Revenue", "Profit"]
        writer = DictWriter(workbook, worksheet, fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()

        for d in data_table:
            warning = (float(real_profit)/float(d['Stat']['revenue']))*100
            row_dict = {"Date": d['Stat']['date'], "Advertiser": d['Advertiser']['company'], "Clicks": d['Stat']['clicks'], "Conversions": d['Stat']['conversions'], "Cost": d['Stat']['payout'], "Revenue": d['Stat']['revenue'], "Profit": d['Stat']['profit']}
            writer.writerow(row_dict)
```

How can I create a `column` with n-1 values which will contain the difference between the value in the current cell in the row X and the previous one?

Thank you!

Comment: Please add some more specific code.

Comment: Ok, I've added an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.read_excel()` or `pd.read_json()` ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html)) to read your excel file /json input into a `pandas.DataFrame`, then create a new column with the first difference of values in an existing column like so ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html)):

```
df['new_col'] = df[['existing_col']].diff()
```